# Stand multi-threaded approach to build the set of all elements in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, concurrency, set

I have an array of elements I want to hash (it's a templated array; or a vector if you like), and an empty hash table. I have a CPU with several cores (and hyperthreading), and want to utilize it as best possible to insert all array elements into the set. Is there code in the STL (or in Boost or some other free library) which does this?

I realize some trivial solutions are:

1. Use a concurrent/thread-safe set (e.g. hash-backed), and just have each thread insert a section of the array.
2. Have each thread create its own set, then repeatedly compute set unions.

But the point is I would rather not write my own but go for commonly-used code. **Edit** also, I want a solution which does not require me to use some specific thread management/pooling system, but which I can just use with arbitrary threads of mine.

**Notes:**

- Needless to say, the set insertion doesn't insert duplicate copies.
- The array may have duplicates (in fact, I expect the number of set elements to be less than 1% of the array length - but cannot assume this always to be the case).
- The set does not need to support element removal, or it can be slow etc.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Intel's Threading Building Blocks ([tbb](/questions/tagged/tbb)) library at http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org. In particular, there is `concurrent_unordered_set` and other concurrency-friendly containers, as well as function templates (e.g. `parallel_for` and `parallel_for_each`) to ease writing parallel code. And TBB is open-source and cross-platform.

The same functionality also exists in Microsoft's Parallel Patterns Library ([ppl](/questions/tagged/ppl)).

A few code sketches for insertion of vector elements into a concurrent_unordered_set. The code is tested with the recent version of TBB, but some parts are omitted for brevity.

```
#include <tbb/tbb.h>
#include <tbb/concurrent_unordered_set.h> // missing in tbb.h

int main() {
  std::vector<MyDataType> v;
  tbb::concurrent_unordered_set<MyDataType> s;

  /* (1) */
  tbb::parallel_for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), [&](const MyDataType& item){
      s.insert(item);
  } );

  /* (2) */
  tbb::parallel_for( size_t(0), size_t(v.size()), [&](size_t i){
      s.insert(v[i]);
  } );

  /* (3) */
  tbb::parallel_for(
      tbb::blocked_range<std::vector<MyDataType>::iterator>(v.begin(), v.end()),
      [&](const tbb::blocked_range<std::vector<MyDataType>::iterator>& range){
          s.insert(range.begin(), range.end()); // inserts a sequence
      }
  );

  return 0;
} // main
```

The variant (1) is the simplest, but also slowest, because `parallel_for_each` currently does not aggregate processing of loop iterations. In this code, the amount of work in a single iteration is too small to justify overheads for task creation and execution.

The variant (2) uses `parallel_for`, which aggregates multiple iterations in a single task, and is therefore much faster while still quite simple.

The variant (3) is the fastest but also most verbose. It explicitly uses `blocked_range`, thus exposing aggregation to the user's code. The benefit out of that is that all vector elements in a given range can be inserted to the set with a single call. It adds a few more percents of performance, and some verbosity can be hidden with e.g. typedefs.

Disclaimer: I am a TBB developer.

Comment: And won't the TBB 'take over' my thread management somehow? Or will it just create its own threads? (Sorry for the late reply)

Comment: For running `parallel_for` and other algorithm templates, TBB uses its own pool of threads, and also utilizes the thread that called the algorithm. However `concurrent_unordered_set` and other containers may be used from any thread, either those created by TBB or other threads in the program.